# cordova/iOS: FileTransfer plugin not working

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, file-transfer

I'm using cordova version 3.3.1 and tried to use the file-transfer plugin on iOS.
I installed the plugin using the commands

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file.git
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-file-transfer.git
cordova prepare ios
```

but `typeof FileTransfer` is `"undefined"`.

Running

```
cordova plugin ls
```

returns

```
[ 'com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner',
  'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer',
  'org.apache.cordova.media',
  'org.apache.cordova.vibration' ]
```

What am I doing wrong here? On android it works as expected.

Comment: is it an option to rebuild the project?  That helps a lot for me when there are plugin issues.

Comment: not right now, I couldn't adjust the project settings again, I'd have to wait for a coworker to return from vacation...